# URLRewrite for Server value removal from Http header response in ISS 8/8.5 for static files?

Tags: security, http-headers, iis-8, url-rewrite-module, iis-8.5

Using "URLRewrite", I were able to set the server header value to "" from IIS handled files. But it is still present in static content files like `<link stylesheets>`, `<script Javascript Files>` included in the header. Please let me know how to fix these issues.

Answer (score 0):

For server tag value removal for all static files like .css/.js files, add this to web.config:

`<configuration>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
</configuration>`

Above mentioned tag makes all the static files to be handled as managed code and hence not through handlers `StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule` and will be handled through `IsapiModule` Handler. This will remove the server tag in the header response for Static files such as .js/.css files.